# How to email a link to a confidential document in Civi

Tags: drupal, civimail, reports, message-templates

A client runs several night shelters for the homeless & uses Civi.  They want to email a 'daily activity' report to staff & volunteers - the content of which is confidential. All staff & volunteers have access to Civi. The report consists of information about who is duty manager, a list of guests with notes and some information about other local homeless accommodation - so much of it is fairly dynamic and could be in a message template, a Word document or spreadsheet. Because it's confidential we don't want to send the actual report in the email, because the receiver of the email would of course retain the email with the report in their account. To avoid this we want to just send an email with a link to the report that's somewhere in Civi. We tried Google Docs but ran into access problems.    Suggestions are very welcome on how this might be achieved in Civi, please!  We're using Drupal, Civi is at 5.19.3, open to using webforms & Views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be building it as a View and setting the Roles for access to the View from there.

Comment: Thanks, Pete.  That's exactly what I've done & it looks good (so far!)

Comment: Cool. Can you pls Accept the answer then

Comment: I already did... and thanks again.

Comment: Hi Andy - I am not seeing that. I see some upvotes on the Answer (so thanks if one of those was you) but I do not see a green tick which is what an Accepted ticket looks like. If you have done that then not sure why I don't see that.

Comment: Ah OK ticked it now

Comment: sweet - Stack Exchange likes it when Qs actually get an accepted Answer